# Input fields not being validated while using Java annotations

Tags: java, validation, annotations, jsf-2.2

I'm having issues understanding how to validate fields in JSF by using annotations. I've read every tutorial I can get my hands on, but nothing. I'm using JSF 2.2 with Tomcat 8.

I'm simply trying to make sure an email fields is at least 5 characters long. That's it. Here's my class and JSP page.

How can I get my message to be displayed and the data validated?

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HTML5 Validation</title>
</head>
<body>

<h:form>
<h:inputText value="#{user.email}" id="email">
</h:inputText>
<h:commandButton action="#{user.runIt}" value="Run it" />
</h:form>

<h:messages/>
</body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

**User.java**

```
package com.jacroe.html5Validation.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class User {

    private String email;

    public String runIt() {
        return "ran";
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(@Size(min=2, message="Size too short") String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look like JSF 2.2 at all to me

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar How should it look like? I'm just lost.

Comment: For example here you can see example of the bean and xhtml: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/. The page should not be jsp, it is considered deprecated. This is a good book, and you can download source code (with examples) for free under "source code/downloads": http://www.apress.com/9781430250104

Comment: This is also a good (but large) tutorial: http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/